# Restoring mac to pre OS install attempt

Tags: macos, mac, installation, operating-systems, disk-utility

I recently tried to install the new OS X maverick, but about 4 min into the process it told me my disk needed to be repaired. That I should back up my stuff and restore the drive.

I will do that, but I would like to just return my computer to its previous state. Is there some way to stop running the OS X install when my computer re-starts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not too much information here about what (OS version, Machine type) you are starting with. So, Guessing:Try holding down the [option key](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) at startup. I'm not 100% sure that will work in this case, but if the computer has a recovery partition and/or is recent enough to do internet recovery, it should work. If it's older, put in a DVD and [press the C key](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533) (no DVD drive - it's probably "newer" in the scale I'm using)